# How to paste without pain russian text in Innosetup script on a non russian localized computer

Tags: inno-setup

I must change the local setting of my computer whenever I want to paste some russian text into a Innosetup script.

It is possible to adress encoding issue within Innosetup itself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should download the Unicode version of Inno Setup. See

- http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode

and download from

- http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php